# How to make IntelliJ IDEA to generate only .iml file?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use the recommended .gitingore file in IntelliJ IDEA project as this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gonaumov/Numeral_System_Converter/stage-1-6/.gitignore .
It keeps part of .idea directory files in version control. When I clone the project on a new PC and try to open it from  IntelliJ IDEA I get  errors like this:

```
21:18 ч.    Load Settings
                Cannot load settings from file '/home/name/Documents/Numeral_System_Converter/Numeral_System_Converter.iml': File /home/name/Documents/Numeral_System_Converter/Numeral_System_Converter.iml does not exist
                Please correct the file content
```

This problem is fixable by just deleting .idea directory. It that case it rebuilds .idea directory and regarding .iml file but I believe this is not the correct approach because why you keep .idea directory if you don't use it? Is there a way to rebuild only the .iml file?
What is the proper solution in that case? I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2 (Edu) but I believe this is a common problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see the error most likely because there is `.idea/modules.xml` file where modules are specified but you have no `.iml` files for them.

If you do not share module's `.iml` files the `.idea/modules.xml` should not be shared also.

Note that if you are using Maven/Gradle/SBT in project you should not share module's `.iml` files, since they are automatically re-generated on **Reload** of the project from Maven/Gradle/SBT.

In case of Maven it is recommended to enable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **Store generated project files externally** option.

In case of Gradle it is recommended to disable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Generate `*.iml` files for modules imported from Gradle** option.

See also [How to manage projects under Version Control Systems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems).

Starting with the 2019.1 version,  IntelliJ can [automatically add to Version Control](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html#share-project-through-vcs) everything that needs sharing.

Comment: You are completely right. I am using exactly the same .gitignore file as they suggest here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems with that change at the bottom of the file:  # Module level configuration
*.iml